# Perform a WebDriverWait() or similar check on a Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to be able to perform something similar to a `WebDriverWait()`, i.e:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//tr[5]/td[11]/div"), "1.000000")
)
```

...for a regular expression, where it waits for an allotted amount of time before failing.  I am aware I could do something, such as...

```
assert re.search(r"[0,1]{1}.[0-9]{6}", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[5]/td[11]/div").text)
```

...or I could replace **search** with **match** in the above example.  The problem with this method is it'll fail if the object.. (1) hasn't loaded yet or.. (2) is still in the process of changing to what's expected. I could do something like...

```
for x in range (1,60):
    try:
        assert re.search(r"[0,1]{1}.[0-9]{6}", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[5]/td[11]/div").text)
    except AssertionError:
        if x < 60:
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            raise AssertionError
```

...where it checks every second for 60 seconds to see if the **assert** statement has evaluated to true.  This could fit into a module or class.  What I'm wondering is if there is a more elegant solution, in Python for the Selenium WebDriver, to handling this that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look into [what an "Expected Condition" is](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py), you would find it easy to *make a custom one*:

```
import re

from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import _find_element


class text_match(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, regexp):
        self.locator = locator
        self.regexp = regexp

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element_text = _find_element(driver, self.locator).text
        return re.search(self.regexp, element_text)
```

Usage:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    text_match((By.XPATH, "//tr[5]/td[11]/div"), r"[0,1]{1}.[0-9]{6}")
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I will spend some time dissecting how it works when I get a chance.  I also believe this will help deepen my understanding of Python.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey @alecxe.  I just finally got around to trying this and received the following error for the **return** statement:  _AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'_

Comment: @rwbyrd yeha, my bad, fixed - please check it out again. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the great answer. It is from 2015 and but the current documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html implements it a little different now.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Selenium, you can do it like this

```
def regex_to_be_present_in_element(locator, regexp):
    """ An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the
    specified element, extended to allow and return a regex match
    locator, text
    """

    def _predicate(driver):
        try:
            element_text = driver.find_element(*locator).text
            return re.search(regexp, element_text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

    return _predicate
```

Usage:

```
match = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    regex_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//tr[5]/td[11]/div"), r"[0,1]{1}.[0-9]{6}")
)
```

You can even access the match groups using `match.groups()`, e.g. to process status/error messages.