# Selenium: Wait until text in WebElement changes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `selenium` with Python 2.7. to retrieve the contents from a search box on a webpage. The search box dynamically retrieves and displays the results in the box itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import re
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

df = pd.read_csv("read.csv")

def crawl(isin):
    searchkey = driver.find_element_by_name("searchkey")
    searchkey.clear()
    searchkey.send_keys(isin)
    sleep(11)

    search_result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results")
    names = re.match(r"^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text).group().encode("utf-8")
    product_id = re.findall(r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)", search_result.text)
    return pd.Series([product_id, names])

df[["insref", "name"]] = df["ISIN"].apply(crawl)

print df
```

Relevant part of the code may be found under `def crawl(isin):`

- The program enters what to search for in the search box (*the box is badly named as* `searchkey`).
- It then does `sleep()` and waits for the content to show in the search box dropdown field `ac_results`.
- Then gets two variables `insrefs` and `names` with Regex.

Instead of calling `sleep()`, I would like for it to wait for the content in the WebElement `ac_results` to load.

Since it will continuously use the search box to get new data by entering new search terms from a list, one could perhaps use Regex to identify when there is new content in `ac_results` that is not identical to the previous content.

Is there a method for this? It is important to note that the content in the search box is dynamically loaded, so the function would have to recognise that something has changed in the WebElement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to apply the [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) concept. E.g. *wait for an element to become visible*:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'searchbox')))
```

Here, it would wait up *to 10* seconds checking the visibility of the element every 500 ms.

There is a set of built-in Expected Conditions to wait for and it is also easy to write your [custom Expected Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848).

---

FYI, here is how we approached it after brainstorming it in the chat. We've introduced a custom Expected Condition that would *wait for the element text to change*. It helped us to identify when the new search results appear:

```
import re

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import _find_element

class text_to_change(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        actual_text = _find_element(driver, self.locator).text
        return actual_text != self.text

#Load URL
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

#Load DataFrame of terms to search for
df = pd.read_csv("searchkey.csv")

#Crawling function    
def crawl(searchkey):
    try: 
        text_before = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results").text 
    except NoSuchElementException: 
        text_before = ""

    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name("searchbox")
    searchbox.clear()
    searchbox.send_keys(searchkey)
    print "\nSearching for %s ..." % searchkey

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        text_to_change((By.CLASS_NAME, "ac_results"), text_before)
    )

    search_result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results")
    if search_result.text != "none":
        names = re.match(r"^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text).group().encode("utf-8")
        insrefs = re.findall(r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)", search_result.text)
    if search_result.text == "none":
        names = re.match(r"^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text)
        insrefs = re.findall(r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)", search_result.text)
    return pd.Series([insrefs, names])

#Run crawl    
df[["Insref", "Name"]] = df["ISIN"].apply(crawl)

#Print DataFrame    
print df
```

Comment: It's not quite that easy, because the `searchbox` element will load instantly when opening the page. It's when I enter the `searchkey` into the element, it'll take up to 8-9 s until the text content in the element loads. It is that content that I would like to wait for.

Comment: @Winterflags yeah, I've just provided an example and a hint :) `text_to_be_present_in_element` is probably a good candidate in your case if you know which text to wait for. If not, then you would need a custom expected condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed your custom expected condition for regex as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240342/perform-a-webdriverwait-or-similar-check-on-a-regular-expression-in-python. I managed to get it waiting for the first reply that matches a pattern, but once that pattern it present it continues to run the loop searching for all searchkeys but not giving it time to conjure them. Do you have any ideas for how to make it wait for new content that matches the same pattern but is different?

Comment: The pattern looks like this: `"Name ABC123 (01234)"`, `"Something 123DEF (432134)"`, `"Somethingsomething 123 GHI (07451)"`. What is constant is that there is text followed by a series of numbers of variable length within parenthesis in the end.

Comment: @Winterflags thanks for trying it out. Could you show me the code you have so far, so that I can start with it? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look at it! I've updated the question with the full code. Unfortunately I don't have a dummy site for you to test it on, as the original is behind user/pw.

Comment: @Winterflags sure, correct me if I'm wrong: you want to wait until the text of the "searchbox" matches all of the pre-defined regex patterns?..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The text retrieved in searchbox will always follow the same pattern `names (insref)` unless it is `"none"`. E.g. `"abcdef (1234)` What will change is the text and numbers in there, and they may be of variable length and spaces. So in the first instance, as the code is doing now, I would like to wait for text to load according to the pattern. But in the second and following instances, I would like for it to wait for the content in the pattern to change.

Comment: @Winterflags I'll be afk for a while, will see what I can do later today, sorry.

Comment: I added a written description to the question of what the code does now. Hope that clarifies a bit what we're looking for.

Comment: Solved this thanks to alecxe in chat! Super helpful. The custom expected condition above will prove useful for Selenium users waiting for dynamic text content to appear in WebElement.

Comment: @Winterflags thanks so much for the additional bounty!

Comment: You're welcome! As a recognition of your helpfulness :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the below Expected Condition in WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "searchbox"), r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)")
)
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CLASS_NAME, "searchbox"), r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)")
)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that will indeed wait for the very first text reply in the search box to be loaded. But if the program inserts a new searchterm right afterwards, it will recognize the pattern from the first result and not wait for the second result to load. See my explanation under "What the code does now" in OP.

Comment: WebDriverWait, that we are using is example of Explicit wait that means we need to set the wait before every element-find. That's why we use implicit wait in start that will set wait for every element-find.

Comment: I believe the best is to use sleep here or write a function to wait for JQuery calls to complete.

Answer (score 1):

create class for wait condition

```
class SubmitChanged(object):
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, driver):
        # here we check if this is new instance of element
        new_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('<your xpath>')
        return new_element != self.element
```

in your program call it

```
     wait = WebDriverWait(<driver object>, 3)
     wait.until(SubmitChanged(<web element>))
```

more info at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html